# Swagger Nodejs - Response Validation Failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-editor

I am building the API with Swagger and NodeJS, the annoying problem I have faced so far is Swagger validates the response, and it's not always smooth.

My case:

In file .yaml: I checked the yaml syntax with Swagger Editor => File Yaml is correct.

```
/user/createNew:
x-swagger-router-controller: xxxxxxx
post:
  tags:
  - User
  summary: Create New User
  # used as the method name of the controller
  operationId: createNewUser
  parameters:
    - name: NewUserReq
      in: body
      required: true
      description: Email register
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/NewUserReq"

  responses:
    "201":
      description: Successful
      schema:
        # a pointer to a definition
        $ref: "#/definitions/CreateUserResp"
    # responses may fall through to errors
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"


CreateUserResp:
properties:
  status:
    type: integer
    description: Response status
  response:
    $ref: "#/definitions/MsgResponse"
MsgResponse:
  required:
    - resp_msg
  properties:
    resp_msg:
     type: string
```

To check the response format, I generated the NodeJs file from Swagger Editor

```
 examples['application/json'] = {
    "response" : {
        "resp_msg" : "aeiou"
     },
    "status" : 123
 };
```

In controller file .js:

```
function createNewUser(req,res){
....

var resp = new Object();
resp.resp_msg=data.email;
final_response.status = 200;
final_response.response = resp;

console.log("createNewUser::Query succeffully", JSON.stringify(final_response)); 
//{"status":200,"response":{"resp_msg":"test@gmail.com"}}

res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.json(final_response);
}
```

Try to run API with Postman, the error happens with log below:

```
Error: Response validation failed: failed schema validation
at throwErrorWithCode (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/lib/validators.js:121:13)
at Object.module.exports.validateAgainstSchema (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/lib/validators.js:176:7)
at /var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:141:22
at /var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:356:13
at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
at _asyncMap (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:355:9)
at Object.map (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:337:20)
at validateValue (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:134:11)
at ServerResponse.res.end (/var/app/current/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-validator.js:252:9)
at ServerResponse.send (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:205:10)
```

I cannot figure out what caused the error, I double checked the structure of JSON response.

Very appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some experiments, I made it work. My solution simply is changing response code "201" to "200" in yaml file, and it worked. I don't know why I left the response code "201". Anyway, I am still new with this, and don't know if it's a best practice or not. I am open to receive any better suggestion.

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have put **required: true** which means you have to pass that parameter otherwise **Response Validation Failed** will appear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce but it gives me some errors. However, I tried removing `MsgResponse` and defining `CreateUserResp` as a single definition, and it worked:

```
CreateUserResp:
  type: object
  properties:
    response:
      type: object
      properties:
        resp_msg:
          type: string
          description: The response object
    status:
      type: number
      description: The status code
```

It seems like you're not defining `response` as an object, and just adding some properties to it.

Comment: Thanks Luis for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I still got the error with your answer.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you don't specify in the header the data type sent within the request body

```
Content-Type : application/json
```